# Change last value of group based on group aggregate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to update the last value of a group to `1` if all the values in the group are `0`.  I would prefer a `tidyverse` solution to go with my overall workflow but others are welcome.  The sample dataset below has two columns `group1` and `group2` to be grouped by, the `value`column where the last value needs to be updated and the results column showing my desired results. I tried conditioning on the sum of the value column per group but wasn't able to make it work. Thanks

```
  df= structure(list(group1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), group2 = c("20171", 
"20171", "20171", "20171", "20171", "20172", "20172", "20172", 
"20172", "20171", "20171", "20171", "20171", "20171", "20172", 
"20172", "20172", "20172"), value = c(`0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 1L, 
`0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, 
`0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, 
`0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, `0.5%` = 0L, 
`0.5%` = 0L), result = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  mutate(result1 = if(all(value == 0)) replace(value, n(), 1) else value)

#   group1 group2 value result result1
#   <chr>  <chr>  <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A      20171      0      0       0
# 2 A      20171      1      1       1
# 3 A      20171      0      0       0
# 4 A      20171      0      0       0
# 5 A      20171      0      0       0
# 6 A      20172      0      0       0
# 7 A      20172      0      0       0
# 8 A      20172      0      0       0
# 9 A      20172      0      1       1
#10 B      20171      0      0       0
#11 B      20171      0      0       0
#12 B      20171      0      0       0
#13 B      20171      0      0       0
#14 B      20171      0      1       1
#15 B      20172      0      0       0
#16 B      20172      0      0       0
#17 B      20172      0      0       0
#18 B      20172      0      1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

this will also work

```
df <- df[1:3]

df %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(row_number() == max(row_number()) & last(cumsum(value)) ==0, 1, value))
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   group1, group2 [4]
   group1 group2 value result
   <chr>  <chr>  <int>  <dbl>
 1 A      20171      0      0
 2 A      20171      1      1
 3 A      20171      0      0
 4 A      20171      0      0
 5 A      20171      0      0
 6 A      20172      0      0
 7 A      20172      0      0
 8 A      20172      0      0
 9 A      20172      0      1
10 B      20171      0      0
11 B      20171      0      0
12 B      20171      0      0
13 B      20171      0      0
14 B      20171      0      1
15 B      20172      0      0
16 B      20172      0      0
17 B      20172      0      0
18 B      20172      0      1
```